# How to access two dimension json array?

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I'm using java 
and i imported

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

Let say I have "freeBaggageAvailable"

```
 "freeBaggageAvailable" : [
    {
        "Y" : [{
                "*" : [{"num":1,"weight": 23,"price": 0}],
               "mc" : [{"num:":1,"weight" : 23,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 23,"price": 0}],
               "mp" : [{"num:":1,"weight" : 23,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 23,"price": 0}],
               "mmc" :[{"num:":1,"weight" : 23,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 32,"price": 0}]
              }],
         "C" : [{
                "*" : [{"num":1,"weight":32 ,"price": 0},{"num":1,"weight":32 ,"price": 0}],
               "mc" : [{"num:":1,"weight" : 32,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 32,"price": 0},{"num":3,"weight":32 ,"price": 0}],
               "mp" : [{"num:":1,"weight" : 32,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 32,"price": 0},{"num":3,"weight":32 ,"price": 0}],
               "mmc" :[{"num:":1,"weight" : 23,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 32,"price": 0}]
              }],

          "F" : [{
                "*" : [{"num":1,"weight":32 ,"price": 0},{"num":1,"weight":32 ,"price": 0}],
               "mc" : [{"num:":1,"weight" : 32,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 32,"price": 0},{"num":3,"weight":32 ,"price": 0},{"num":4,"weight":32 ,"price": 0}],
               "mp" : [{"num:":1,"weight" : 32,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 32,"price": 0},{"num":3,"weight":32 ,"price": 0},{"num":4,"weight":32 ,"price": 0}],
               "mmc" :[{"num:":1,"weight" : 23,"price": 0}, {"num":2, "weight": 32,"price": 0},{"num":4,"weight":32 ,"price": 0}]
              }]}
     ],
```

if I want to access to the data  "Y" -> "mc" -> "num"

how to access it fron JsonObject

```
 File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("files/BaggageInfoPolicy.json").getFile());

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow – make sure you [read the guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions. This question seems a little unclear. Try to make your questions easier to answer and you might find more responses.

Comment: Please add a tag for which language you are wishing to load this in using, and please add which JSON library you are using. It would also be helpful to show the expected output - i.e. what exactly do you expect to retrieve/how you wish it to be structured when loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON.org reference implementation, you could do:

```
for (String key : JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject))
{
    map.put(key, jsonObject.get(key));
}
```

In JSON simple, you would do:

```
for (Object keyObject : jsonObject.keySet())
{
    String key = (String)keyObject;
    map.put(key, (String)jsonObject.get(key));
}
```